# Authentication failure FireBase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the `createAccount()` method from Firebase Authentication and I have attached two listeners :
`addOnSuccessListener`and `addOnFailureListener`

1. When I'm creating an account and at the same time loosing the internet connection, the account is successfully created (I can see it in Firebase console) whereas the `onFailure` listener is called.
2. Also, when I'm creating this account, I am saving a User object in Firestore with a `Task<Void>` called asynchronously from the auth method. The problem is that this user is never created in Firestore Database because of the previous failure but has got an authentication account anyway.

The result is that the user is able to log in but does not exist in the database and thus all his fields are null.

I could not find any rollbacks on the Firebase auth methods, so for now on I am logging in the user and at this time checking if a User object with the same email exists in the database... But I don't think this is a good approach

So how to handle a such scenario ?

EDIT : code I'm using

```
firebaseAPI.createAccount(email, password, userName).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
        System.out.println("onSuccess: the firebase user is not null.");
        final FirebaseUser currentUser = authResult.getUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            // Send an email to verify the new account created
            currentUser.sendEmailVerification()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            System.out.println("onSuccess: email verification has been sent.");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("onFailure: failed to send the emailVerification.");
                            System.out.println("onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

            System.out.println("onComplete: registering the username.");

            // Update the display name of the firebaseUser object
            final UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName(userName).build();

            currentUser.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("onFailure: failed to update the user display name.");
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    System.out.println("onSuccess: display name updated.");
                    System.out.println("onSuccess: writing batch.");
                    String uid = currentUser.getUid();
                    // Fields to register in Firestore Database.
                    final User userToRegister = new User(uid, userName, email, birthDate, lastName, firstName);
                    // Register the Username in Firestore Database & the user as the same time to rollback everything if something happens.
                    firebaseAPI.createUser(userToRegister, uid).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            System.out.println("onSuccess: logging the user in.");
                            onSignUpSuccess(userToRegister);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
                            System.out.println("onFailure: sending error to the activity");
                            if (e.getMessage().contains("offline") || e.getMessage().contains("internal error")) {
                                onSignUpError(SignUpErrorType.INTERNET_FAILED);
                            }
                            else {
                                onSignUpError(SignUpErrorType.GENERIC_ERROR);
                            }
                            deleteUser(currentUser);
                        }
                    }).addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCanceled() {
                            System.out.println("onCanceled: batch canceled.");
                            onSignUpError(SignUpErrorType.GENERIC_ERROR);
                            deleteUser(currentUser);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        System.out.println("onFailure: " + e.getMessage());
        if (e.getMessage().contains("internal error") || e.getMessage().contains("network error")) {
            // equals("An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ]")
            System.out.println("onFailure: sending error to the activity");
            onSignUpError(SignUpErrorType.INTERNET_FAILED);
        } else if (e.getMessage().contains("mail")){
            System.out.println("onFailure: sending error to the activity");
            System.out.println("onFailure: error is : " + e.getMessage());
            onSignUpError(SignUpErrorType.EMAIL_ALREADY_TAKEN);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("onFailure: error is : " + e.getMessage());
            onSignUpError(SignUpErrorType.GENERIC_ERROR);
        }
    }
});
```

Error in logcat :

```
I/System.out: onFailure: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

Comment: If your failure listener is triggered, then you should log the exception it provides to find out what went wrong.  Please edit the question to include its error message, as well as the code you're using.

Comment: The problem is not the error, i turned off my internet connection with a good timing intentionnally to simulate the error that may happen for any user.
The problem is how to handle this situation when it happens. (I am also surprised that both OnSuccess AND OnFailure are called for the same task)